# Is in Typescript possible to define 'object of arrays of type string? (right position of type checking?)

Tags: typescript

I know in typescript an object can be typed either by ClassName (ES6 class) or by 'any'.

I also know you can define an array of string (string[]) and even an array of arrays of string (string[][]).

I need to express the type of an **object** whose properties are **only** arrays of type string.

e.g.

```
export var MY_VAR: any = {
    <string[]> p1: [...]
}
```

I tried with something like **any** following **object_name:** but not luck.

I also tried **any** following object_name and  before each object's array.

In either case I have **syntax errors** (see example above)

**EDIT** apparently

```
export var MY_VAR: any = {
    <string[]> p1: [...]
}
```

works instead. however I don't understand **what the difference is**

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's not very clear what you're asking for, but if I managed to get you right then:

```
interface MyType {
    [key: string]: string[];
}
```

Or inline:

```
let myArrays: { [key: string]: string[] } = {};
```

Comment: thanks. can you just clarify the difference between **<string[]> p1** and **p1: string[]** (see my 1st and 2nd example)?

Comment: Basically `<string[]> p1` means casting `p1` to a string array (`string[]` which is like `Array<string>`).  But in your example you cast the key to be a string array instead of the value.  But even if you'd cast the value, it's just one specific value, it means nothing about the object itself (which you defined as `any`)