# write an object with keys and array typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am writing the following in typescript and see the following error

```
const WEEKDAYS_SHORT = {
    en: ['S', 'M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S'],
    de: ['S', 'M', 'D', 'M', 'D', 'F', 'S'],
};

<StyledDayPicker weekdaysShort={WEEKDAYS_SHORT[language]} />
```

> Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type '[string, string, string, string, string, string, string]'.
>     Property '0' is missing in type 'string[]'. [2322]

I have tried the following which is giving me an error.

```
const WEEKDAYS_SHORT: string[] = {
    en: ['S', 'M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S'],
    de: ['S', 'M', 'D', 'M', 'D', 'F', 'S'],
};
```

Comment: You're defining the type as an array of strings but you're declaring your variable with an object....

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36860251/is-in-typescript-possible-to-define-object-of-arrays-of-type-string-right-pos

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is in Typescript possible to define 'object of arrays of type string? (right position of type checking?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36860251/is-in-typescript-possible-to-define-object-of-arrays-of-type-string-right-pos)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`weekdaysShort` expects a string tuple of length 7. By default typescript infers arrays of fir array literals. The simple solution is to usa an extra function to help inference along:

```
const stringTuple = <T extends string[]>(...a: T) => a;

const WEEKDAYS_SHORT = {
    en: stringTuple('S', 'M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S'),
    de: stringTuple('S', 'M', 'D', 'M', 'D', 'F', 'S')
};
```

Or you can use a type assertion:

```
type Tuple7 = [string,string,string,string,string,string,string]
const WEEKDAYS_SHORT = {
    en: ['S', 'M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S'] as Tuple7,
    de: ['S', 'M', 'D', 'M', 'D', 'F', 'S'] as Tuple7,
};
```

Or in typescript 3.4 (unreleased at this time) you can assert `as const` to make the compiler infer a readonly tuple:

```
const WEEKDAYS_SHORT = {
    en: ['S', 'M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S'],
    de: ['S', 'M', 'D', 'M', 'D', 'F', 'S'],
} as const;
```

Also depending on your compiler setting, and the `language` should be `'en' | 'de'` for indexing to work.

Comment: any idea for this one 'Typescript King' - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54575523/issue-with-passing-hook-to-child-typescript

Comment: @peterflanagan :)) I can have a look

Comment: I think I have figured it out/the answer there answers it. It is a react issue not a ts one

Answer (score 0):

Your variable should be defined as such:

```
const WEEKDAYS_SHORT: { [prop: string]: string[] } = {
    en: ['S', 'M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S'],
    de: ['S', 'M', 'D', 'M', 'D', 'F', 'S'],
};
```

Comment: it is still complaining . Also is prop a keyword, or can I use anything there. As said below it is because it is expecting a string tuple of length 7. I didn't know this