# issue with passing hook to child typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have a react component using hooks. My parent component looks like this:

```
const Parent = () => {

   const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);

   return (
     <Child isActive={isActive} setIsActive={setIsActive} />
   );
}
```

and here is the child component

```
type Props = {
   isActive: boolean;
   setIsActive: () => void;
}
const Child = ({ isActive, setIsActive}: Props) {
   // component
}
```

the error I am seeing is

> Type error: Type 'Dispatch < SetStateAction>' is not assignable to > type '() => void'.  TS2322

Comment: setIsActive function should always return new state for the isActive. so, you cannot use type () => void; void means, you are not returning value. try to fix void by any (or type of the isActive).

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Your `Props` type for `Child` is incorrect.  React types the `setIsActive` as `Dispatch`, which is defined as:

```
type Dispatch<A> = (value: A) => void;
```

You're missing the `value` argument from your type.  This should be correct:

```
type Props = {
   isActive: boolean;
   setIsActive: (active: boolean) => void;
}
const Child = ({ isActive, setIsActive}: Props) {
   // rest of the component
}
```